# Classification of rental property closing costs?

Tags: united-states, real-estate, tax-deduction

I understand rental property closing costs fall into 3 buckets:

1. added to cost basis of property for purposes of calculating depreciation (title costs, transfer and government fees, inspections, etc)
2. deductible as current costs in the year they are paid (taxes, insurance)
3. amortized over the cost of the loan (loan origination costs, appraisal if required by bank, etc)

The first two items above get reported on Schedule E.

My question is on what form does the third item above get reported?

Comment: Just a guess: if you lump them into the loan, they fall into bucket #1. If you pay them upfront at closing, then bucket #2.

Comment: @TTT...thanks, but no. Bucket #1 gets depreciated over 27.5 years. Bucket #2 all gets deducted in the current year. Bucket #3 gets amortized over 30 years (loan term in this case). The question is where. The more I read Publication 527 and Schedule E, I believe these costs fall under "Points" and get entered on Line 12 of Schedule E.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean:  https://www.irs.gov/publications/p527/ch02.html#en_US_2016_publink1000219057 "The following are settlement fees and closing costs you cannot include in your basis in the property." and Appraisal is one of those.

Comment: See http://www.thedancingaccountant.com/?p=353

Comment: @bishop...thanks for the suggestion, but that didn't help much